# React Native textinput value issues

Tags: react-native

I am stuck with a very simple problem. I have a form with an `usd` input and a `cny` input, I want when I input one of them, the other will show a value by caculation.

**Example**
[image]

```js
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native';
    class Buy extends Component {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = {
                usd: '',
                cny: ''
            };
        }
      render() {
       return (
        <View style={styles.inputSection}>
            <View style={styles.leftInputSection}>
                <Text style={styles.inputLabel}>USD</Text>
                <TextInput 
                    placeholder='0.0'
                    placeholderTextColor='#999999'
                    style={styles.inputStyle}
                    keyboardType={'numeric'}
                    onChangeText={(usd) => this.setState({ usd })}
                    value={((this.state.cny) * 7).toString()}
                />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.rightInputSection}>
                <Text style={styles.inputLabel}>CNY</Text>
                <TextInput 
                    placeholder='0.0'
                    placeholderTextColor='#999999'
                    style={styles.inputStyle}
                    keyboardType={'numeric'}
                    onChangeText={(cny) => this.setState({ cny })}
                    value={((this.state.usd) / 7).toString()}
                />
            </View>
        </View>
     );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use other textInput state as the value. As @Mayank snippet, setState *usd* & *cny* in the onChangeText of two textInput:

```js
     <TextInput
      placeholder='0.0'
      placeholderTextColor='#999999'
      style={styles.inputStyle}
      keyboardType={'numeric'}
      onChangeText={(usd) => this.setState({cny: usd * 7, usd: usd})}
      value={(this.state.usd).toString()}
    />
    <TextInput
      placeholder='0.0'
      placeholderTextColor='#999999'
      style={styles.inputStyle}
      keyboardType={'numeric'}
      onChangeText={(cny) => this.setState({cny: cny, usd: cny / 7})}
      value={(this.state.cny).toString()}
    />
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this is what you want, Check this example, replace the `input` element by the `TextInput` and specify other properties also:

```js
class App extends React.Component{

   constructor(){
      super();
      this.state = {a: '', b: ''}
   }
   
   render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <input
            value={this.state.a}
            onChange={(e)=>this.setState({b: e.target.value *7, a: e.target.value})}
          />
          <input
            value={this.state.b}
            onChange={(e)=>this.setState({a: e.target.value/7, b: e.target.value})}
          />
        </div>
      )
   }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='app'/>
```

**Note**: It's a solution for web, to use the code in react-native you need to do the changes, like inside `onChange` replace `e.target.value`
by what `react-native onChange` provides etc.

Comment: Your answer is for react, not react native. React native textInput "onChange" not providing *e* parameter, it is just provide value of input.

Comment: @MeysamIzadmehr stackoverflow is not for writing someones code, it a place to give the idea or solution of your issues, i clearly mentioned that in my answer, to replace the `input` element and do the changes, replacing `e` with what the `onChange` of react-native provides is not a big thing, i gave him a working solution for web, anyone with very basic knowledge of react-native can convert it easily. Btw if you think you can provide a better solution directly in native you can also add a new answer :)

Comment: You can't use *e.target.value* in react native textInput onChange.

Comment: read the above comment again, and try to understand what i am saying, **he can replace e with what the onChange of react-native textInput field provides is not a big thing**, its a working solution for web he need to convert that in native that's all, main point was how to manage the state variable :)

Comment: Not a big thing, just a detail:)